# Is there a better way of writing this loop?

Tags: java, loops

I need to check whether at least 1 item in a list has X, Y, and Z (not all at the same time). e.g. item 1 has x, and item 2 has y and z.

I thought it'd be better to do this without creating multiple loops and just checking for one of them, but instead store a variable and then check it so it can't be set to false again once true.

Seems like I'm probably missing a better way to do this, so is there one?

Thanks

```java
        boolean hasX = false;
        boolean hasY = false;
        boolean hasZ = false;

        for (ItemType item : Items) {
            if (!hasX) { hasX = DoesHaveX(item); }
            if (!hasY) { hasY = DoesHaveY(item); }
            if (!hasZ) { hasZ = DoesHaveZ(item); }
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, yeah it's meant to be passed in. Will edit

Comment: You can `break` once you've found all 3, (and other things like store in a bit-set for space, blah blah).  But I can't think of a significant improvement here :/

Comment: Yeah, good idea. Thank you :)

Comment: Same here. This is straight forward, dont overthink it.

Comment: There is a specific site for code review, https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @JoakimDanielson in its current form the question would be closed in a heartbeat on Code Review

Comment: You could use `items.forEach(item -> {...});`, but that wouldn't improve anything, it would just do it in a Java-8-way...

Comment: You can just put the logic for checking with the `if` inside of the method `DoesHaveX` etc.  and make it set `hasX` accordingly, instead of having the logic in the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to stick to a JVM below 1.8 then your code is just fine!

Maybe you could skip few operations like breaking the loop once you found a match for the three booleans, and checking only those which are not found any yet.

```
    for (ItemType item : items) {

        hasX = hasX || doesHaveX(item);
        hasY = hasY || doesHaveY(item);
        hasZ = hasZ || doesHaveZ(item);

        if (hasX && hasY && hasZ) {

            break;
        }
    }
```

If you are just fine to use streams maybe it's better to initialize each of the variables at it's creation like so:

```
    boolean hasX = items.stream().anyMatch(this::doesHaveX); // goes trough the elements until a match is found.
    boolean hasY = items.stream().anyMatch(this::doesHaveY); // goes trough the elements until a match is found.
    boolean hasZ = items.stream().anyMatch(this::doesHaveZ); // goes trough the elements until a match is found.
```

Comment: I like your last code example for its simplicity: it's obvious what is happening. It even stops early when it already found it match. Well done

Comment: I think that the OP is asking the wrong question here and therefore the answer will not fit his expectations... Maybe he will have to improve the abstractions he's implemented so far to get a code that looks just fine...

Answer (score 0):

A Stream map/reduce version of the loop for fun. Not sure if it is better to be honest. But at least we get rid of all the variables

- map each item to a list of 3 booleans (one for each attribute x,y,z)
- reduce the whole list into a list of 3 booleans (one for each attribute x,y,z) checking if any of the items has each value
- check that all the elements of the the resulting list are true.

```
boolean allGood = items.stream()
    .map(i -> Arrays.asList(doesHaveX(i), doesHaveY(i), doesHaveZ(i)))
    .reduce(Arrays.asList(false, false, false),
            (acc, elem) -> Arrays.asList(acc.get(0) || elem.get(0), 
                                         acc.get(1) || elem.get(1), 
                                         acc.get(2) || elem.get(2)))
    .stream()
    .allMatch(Boolean::booleanValue);
```

Comment: So many allocations via `Arrays.asList` :(. And `Arrays.asList(false, false, false)` is really ugly and unusual haha. But yeah, nice functional approach

Comment: yes, but I don't know if the stream optimizes it internally. We would need to make some tests for that. Unless somebody knows.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an extendable approach that uses an enum so you never have to touch the logic of `hasOneOfAll` again. You just have to extend the given enum.

```
import java.util.EnumMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.function.Predicate;

class StackOverflowQuestion56902308Scratch {
    class ItemType {
        boolean x;
        boolean y;
        boolean z;
    }

    enum ItemTypeCheck implements Predicate<ItemType> {
        HASX() {
            @Override
            public boolean test(ItemType itemType) {
                //TODO: implement me
                return itemType.x;
            }
        },
        HASY() {
            @Override
            public boolean test(ItemType itemType) {
                //TODO: implement me
                return itemType.y;
            }
        },
        HASZ() {
            @Override
            public boolean test(ItemType itemType) {
                //TODO: implement me
                return itemType.z;
            }
        }
    }

    public static boolean hasOneOfAll(List<ItemType> itemTypes) {
        Map<ItemTypeCheck, Boolean> result = new EnumMap<>(ItemTypeCheck.class);
        for (ItemType itemType : itemTypes) {
            for (ItemTypeCheck check : ItemTypeCheck.values()) {
                result.merge(check, check.test(itemType), Boolean::logicalOr);
            }
        }

        return result.values().stream().allMatch(hadOne -> hadOne);
    }

}
```

Personally I am not sure if this is too overengineered but it alleviates the pain of manually adjusting the function if another check is added in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add a `BitSet` variant too, and under the assumption that checking `has...` is a semi-expensive operation:

```
private static final int xBit = 0;
private static final int yBit = 1;
private static final int zBit = 2;

public static boolean hasAll(final Collection<ItemType> items) {
    if (items.isEmpty()) return false;

    final BitSet bits = new BitSet(3);

    for (final ItemType item : items) {

        // Check if bit is already set to avoid
        // needless `has*` evaluation
        if (!bits.get(xBit) && hasX(item)) bits.set(xBit);

        if (!bits.get(yBit) && hasY(item)) bits.set(yBit);

        if (!bits.get(zBit) && hasZ(item)) bits.set(zBit);

        // You could repeat this INSIDE all of the 'if's
        // above to potentially avoid computing bits.get
        // but I'd sacrifice that for the slightly improved
        // readability.
        if (bits.cardinality() == 3) return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

I can't tell you if this is faster or anything, as that depends on your `has*` implementations, amongst other things.  But it avoids most recomputations whereever possible.